# Hashtable SORT in J2ME

Tags: sorting, java-me, hashtable

is there any way to sort a Hashtable in J2ME? because I'm trying to adapt the bubble sort to this case but I did not find a solution. Could anybody help me please?

Comment: A Hashtable has no defined order and therefore can't be sorted. If you need something sorted, put it in a `List` (or a `Vector`).

Comment: @JoachimSauer as opposed to Java SE, in j2me CLDC there's no `List` in [java.util](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/package-frame.html "package javadocs"). Neither Comparator etc. Sorting is expected to be coded by developer; or taken from 3rd party libraries

Comment: So, I could move to a Vector and then sorted. After that Could I add the sorted values into the source Hashtable? j2me respects the order insertion in the hashtable?

Comment: @m4g4bu: no, a `Hashtable` *has no defined order*. So it doesn't matter if you insert it in sorted order, it will not be sorted afterwards. (That's the same with the Java SE `HashMap` by the way).

Comment: @gnat: I know, that's why I even mentioned `Vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a Vector or array.

In this question you can check an implementation of the sort:

[How to sort a Vector of String in java-me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569414/how-to-sort-a-vector-of-string-in-java-me)